# Kendo UI Core ViewModel and Basic Databinding

Tags: kendo-ui

I am having trouble getting basic databinding working.
It seems that I have to use .fetch for databinding to work. I feel this way isn't correct, plus the save method isn't called. Also the TabStrip has stopped working when using this method.

Is it always necessary to use the kendo application constructor at the end of each page? In another page if I use it the page does not show ???

I'm very new to Kendo.

The Json returned is

```
[{"JobID":8,"JobDescription":"Lets try these for apples","JobTemplateID":1,"JobTemplateName":"Standard Service","JobSignature":null,"JobNotes":null,"AssetName":null,"SiteName":"??? ","LocationName":"??? ","Priority":"???","JobLoggedOn":"2015-01-09T15:28:14","JobEstimatedStart":"2015-01-09T15:28:04.76","JobCompletedOn":null,"AssignedToName":"???"}]
```

and the code is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Job Details</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/Styles/Kendo/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/Styles/Kendo/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/Styles/Kendo/kendo.dataviz.mobile.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/Styles/Kendo/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

    <script src="Scripts/Kendo/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Kendo/kendo.core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Kendo/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Kendo/kendo.mobile.button.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Kendo/kendo.mobile.listview.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Kendo/kendo.mobile.tabstrip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Kendo/kendo.mobile.modalview.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Signature/jSignature.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="view" id="tabstrip-details" data-title="Details" data-layout="mobile-tabstrip">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group">
            <li>General Details
            <ul>
                <li>Site <span class="value" data-bind="text: jobDetails.SiteName"></span></li>
                <li>Location <span class="value" data-bind="text: jobDetails.LocationName"></span></li>
                <li>Asset <span class="value" data-bind="text: jobDetails.AssetName"></span></li>
                <li>Priority <span class="value" data-bind="text: jobDetails.Priority"></span></li>
                <li>Template <span class="value" data-bind="text: jobDetails.JobTemplateName"></span></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Dates and Assignee
            <ul>
                <li>Assigned To <span class="value" data-bind="text: jobDetails.AssignedToName"></span></li>
                <li>Estimated Start <span class="value" data-bind="text: jobDetails.JobEstimatedStart"></span></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="view" id="tabstrip-notes" data-title="Notes" data-layout="mobile-tabstrip">
    </div>

    <div data-role="view" id="tabstrip-steps" data-title="Steps" data-layout="mobile-tabstrip">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group">
            <li>Before Starting
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" />Step 1</label></li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" />Step 2</label></li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" />Step 3</label></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Step by Step
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" />Do This</label></li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" />Do This</label></li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" />Do This</label></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="view" id="tabstrip-parts" data-title="Parts" data-layout="mobile-tabstrip">
    </div>

    <div data-role="view" id="tabstrip-photos" data-title="Photos" data-layout="mobile-tabstrip">
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>

    <div data-role="view" id="tabstrip-done" data-title="Finish Job" data-layout="mobile-tabstrip">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group">
            <li>Completed On
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        Date
                        <input type="date" data-bind="value: jobDetails.JobCompletedOn" />
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        Time
                    <input type="time" data-bind="value: jobDetails.JobCompletedOn" />
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Sign Off
            <ul>
                <li>Signature <span class="value"><a data-role="button" data-rel="modalview" href="#modalview-sign">Sign Here</a></span></li>
            </ul>
            </li>

            <li>Submit
                 <button data-bind="click: save">Job Done</button>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>


    <div data-role="layout" data-id="mobile-tabstrip">
        <header data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <a class="nav-button" data-align="left" href="Home.html#JobList.html">Back</a>
                <span data-role="view-title"></span>
            </div>
        </header>


        <div data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="tabstrip">
                <a href="#tabstrip-details" data-icon="about">Details</a>
                <a href="#tabstrip-notes" data-icon="organize">Notes</a>
                <a href="#tabstrip-steps" data-icon="share">Steps</a>
                <a href="#tabstrip-parts" data-icon="cart">Parts</a>
                <a href="#tabstrip-photos" data-icon="camera">Photos</a>
                <a href="#tabstrip-done" data-icon="compose">Finish Job</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="modalview" id="modalview-sign" style="width: 90%; height: 70%">
        <div data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <a data-align="right" data-click="closeModalView" data-role="button">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="signature"></div>
    </div>


    <style scoped>
        .value {
            float: right;
            margin-top: 8px;
            color: #bbb;
        }
    </style>

    <script>

        $("#signature").jSignature();

        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/api/job/getjob/8",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                update: {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/api/job/SaveJob",
                },
            }
        });

        dataSource.fetch(function () {
            var data = dataSource.data();
            var job = data[0];
            var viewModel = kendo.observable({
                jobDetails: job,
                save: function () {
                    this.dataSource.sync();
                }

            });
            kendo.bind(document.body, viewModel);
        });

        var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);

    </script>


    <script>
        function closeModalView() {
            $("#modalview-sign").kendoMobileModalView("close");
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't bind your ViewModel in the fetch callback. A more standard patern would be to put the DataSource itself in the ViewModel. You should post up some more code about the page itself and what is being bound. At the moment, I have no idea what you are trying to acheive. I only know how you are trying to and I cannot guide you in the right direction without knowning the destination.

Comment: Thankyou for this reply. Just quickly I just read that datasource does not work with single records. It expects an array. I was able to get a list of items to work correctly. Perhaps its not worth using the datasource ?  Ill post the full page once I receive permission.

Comment: I find it very weird that you want a datasource with a single record. From where I stand, I'd say you have a pattern problem in your application. But if your are CERTAIN that you want to do this, than yes, I would forget about the datasource and simply use an ObservableObject (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject) bound to your view and put a simple $.ajax() call in your viewmodel's save method. DataSource is made to simplify managing multiple rows of data. Theres no benifit to use it for a single record.

Comment: Thankyou for your feedback. How do kendo users normally handle a detail form with results coming from Web API.  Basically most of the app will be list of records then View Detail and Edit. I'm not certain of anything Pluc, I'm new to Kendo and Web API. I have it up and running in knockout.js but I was very impressed by Kendo GUI components + the offline capability of the datasource. I guess one way is to modify the Web API to always return an array. Is this what is done ?   Thankyou.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I cannot tell you what "kendo users" usually do because I do not use Kendo Mobile, only the standard Kendo UI. When making a standard website with Kendo control, you would handle a List > Details scenario with a Grid or a ListView. Those controls would be bound to a DataSource. You can then use the Grid's Popup editor to acheive editing your details et a Detail Template to show more info without going into the editor.